# cxDBnavigator applies sorting independent of the grid's settings

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe, delphi-xe4, devexpress-windows-ui

In the grid's properties I have selected one column to sort records (sort order) ASC.Works OK.However, when I use the cxDBNavigator and try and go to the last record, it does not go to the last record in the grid but the last record entered in the database. What is the use of using the sorting properties of the grid if the dbnavigator does not follow? Is there a way to correct this (apart from sorting records in code) ?

Comment: Have you considered using the navigator built into the grid? No additional code required to sync the navigation to the sorting.

Comment: Too small the buttons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CxDBNavigator is navigating in the dataset, not in the grid.
Since the data in the cxGridDBTableView or cxGridDBBandedTableView is sorted in the grid you will have to take **cxNavigator** instead of **cxDBNavigator** and bind either the view or the grid to the property **Control** of the cxNavigator.